# after platform execution AAPT: error:/lStar not found. error: failed linking references. Execution failed for task processReleaseResources. ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmn4J.png)

i am getting this error  after android platform build
when i this command getting error check in screenshot help me
[ionic build --release android]
Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> values.xml:2422:5-2449:25: AAPT: error: resource /lStar not found.

error: failed linking references.

- Try:
  Run with  option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
25 actionable tasks: 25 executed
Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.